# How to give 100 percent CPU usage to a process

Tags: performance, cpu, process, speed, cpu-usage

(windows 8.1 machine with i3)
Is it possible to put a process using 100% of my CPU?

I have a rather "slow poke" CPU and after a while working with an application, it gets really slow.

I'm wondering if it is possible to give that application the ability to use all of the processing power in order to make it faster.

I already set the priority to realtime on task manager and the affinity is for all 4 processors...

Does this depend on who programmed the app?

Comment: Memory leaks can cause similar behavior.  Unfortunately, this is up to the application developer to fix.  You may look for an updated version of your application.

Answer (score 3):

Long story short, **no**.

In order for Windows to even function, there are a number of services and processes that are constantly running. In order to dedicate 100% of your CPU to one process, you would essentially need to not have an operating system, in which case the process likely could not run anyway.

By default, applications will use as much CPU usage that they can get, unless they give you an option to throttle the usage.

Comment: And, to add to this: Setting the affinity is only for restricting. Setting priority does absolutely nothing, unless there's multiple processes competing for resources.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot give exclusive CPU rights to any single process. **PERIOD**

The App requests resources from the OS to make sure everything remains stable and operational

Why you ask? It would be so excellent you say?

Think about this scenario:

> You have a true dual-core, no hyper-threading
>
> Give Excel 100% of Core 1
>
> Give Word 100% of Core 2
>
> Wanna watch a YouTube video while Excel is open? think again...
>
> Also, how is Windows supposed to juggle it's background processes

I know this was a little brash but I hope it clears up your misconception of why you think your idea is good.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that your application might be using resources other than the CPU.  In your case, if you're upped its priority and you're still not seeing full CPU usage, it's probably waiting for disk or network I/O... and there's very little you can do about speeding that up other than buying new hardware!